# perform substring extraction on data frame column

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe with 1 column called 'full_url'. Each element of the column is just a url.  How to I write a function to remove the 'http://' from all of the elements at once? I need to use some kind of regex because some don't have it at all, some have https, etc. The closest I've gotten is `gsub(".*//","",unlist(full_url))`

but that also returns 'full_url1' 'full_url2' 'full_url3' ... as the row names for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example I'm not sure, but would something like this work?

```
apply(df$full_url, 1, function(x) ifelse(substr(x,1,7) == "http://", substr(x,8,length(x)),x)
```

So using apply to go by row and substr to find if the first 7 characters are "http://". If they are replace without the http and if they're not then replace with just x.

Comment: `substr` is already vectorised, there is no need to apply it row-by-row. You can avoid the `apply` wrapper here altogether.